# How to append an array to the start of a matrix in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to append a numpy array to the first spot in a numpy matrix.

```
mean = 0.000
Standard_deviation  = 0.012
num_samples = 500
Starting_W = 10000
```

Trying to take the matrix:

```
Projections = np.random.normal(mean, Standard_deviation, size=(1000,num_samples))
```

And add the array:

```
W_Array = np.array(np.repeat(Starting_W, num_samples))
```

Which the code:

```
 Projections[1,:]
```

Will return all 10000 which was the Starting_W value.

How is the best way to do this?

Comment: What's the shape (and dtype) of the matrix, before and aftervthe 'append'?

Comment: [np.concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) or np.hstack ? Note this is not efficient in a loop.